# Issue with connecting to .mdf file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2017

I have an issue connecting to my `.mdf` database file in Visual Studio 2017

This is my connection string:

```
Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=true;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|MyDB.mdf;User Instance=true;
```

Error code I get :

> MyDB.mdf cannot be opened because it is version 852. This server supports version 663 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported

How can I update the server?

Comment: Install a newer SQL Server

Comment: You can install a newer version from MS SQL Server site.

Comment: Version 663 (which you have) is SQL Server **2008 R2** - while the `.mdf` database file has version 852 (which is SQL Server **2016**).  In order to use that `.mdf` file, your server **must also be** at LEAST SQL Server **2016** - so you need to install that newer version to use that file

Answer (score 0):

You can open a sql server 2005 file on a higher version,such as 2016, the opposite is not possible, you tried the opposite.